# RecyclerView adapterNotifychanged doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview in fragment. When I click the recyclerview item, background color changes. But when I go to another activity and go back, pressed item color stayed.

I have called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but nothing happened.

Here is my RecyclerView.ViewHolder class

```
  class GreetingsView(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var imageView: ImageView? = null
        var category: TextView? = null
        var frameLayout: FrameLayout? = null
        var context: Context? = itemView.context
        private var listOfGreetings: List<GreetingModel>? = null

        init {
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.greetingImage)
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.greetingCategory)
            frameLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view)
            this.listOfGreetings = listOfGreetings
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val position = adapterPosition

                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    frameLayout?.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
                    val intent = Intent(context, GridGreetingListActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("position", position)
                    context?.startActivity(intent)

                }else {
                    frameLayout?.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Here is my Fragment

```
class CategoryFragment : Fragment(), SendItemPositionListener {

    var greetingAdapter: GreetingAdapter? = null
    var listOfGreetings: ArrayList<GreetingModel>? = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        listOfGreetings?.apply {
            add(0, GreetingModel("Greeting 1", R.drawable.img_1))
            add(1,
                GreetingModel("Greeting 2", R.drawable.greeting_1)
            )
            add(2, GreetingModel("Greeting 3", R.drawable.img_3))
            add(3, GreetingModel("Greeting 4", R.drawable.img_4))
            add(4, GreetingModel("Greeting 5", R.drawable.img_5))
            add(5, GreetingModel("Greeting 6", R.drawable.img_6))
            add(6, GreetingModel("Greeting 7", R.drawable.img_7))
            add(7, GreetingModel("Greeting 8", R.drawable.img_8))
        }


        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)

        //Get the recyclerView from the inflated view.
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = manager
        greetingAdapter = GreetingAdapter(activity!!, listOfGreetings!!.toList())
        recyclerView.adapter = greetingAdapter

        greetingAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

        return view

    }
```

I am not sure that I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in right place. Hope you will help!

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` right after creating and setting up the adapter does nothing, because dataset has not changed between it's initialization and the call. I'm not sure why would you expect viewholder color to change, if you're in "next" activity only for a moment your activity with `RecyclerView` will only be paused and views aren't recreated.

Comment: any advice to organize color changing  in right way? Can I call notifyDataSetChanged() in onPause() method?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: When I click on recyclerview item, it changes color and go to another activity. But when I go back, clicked item color stayed. I want to refresh adapter so that the color disappeare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution of my problem. It is needed to call `setOnClickListener` on `itemView` in `onBindViewHolder` but not in `ViewHolder` and call `greetingAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()` on `onResume()` method.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GreetingsView, position: Int) {

        holder.category?.text = listOfGreetings?.get(position)?.greetingCategory
        holder.cardView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        Glide
            .with(context?.applicationContext!!)
            .load(listOfGreetings?.get(position)?.imageId)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .fitCenter()
            )
            .into(holder.imageView!!)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            holder.cardView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)

            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                val intent = Intent(context, GridGreetingListActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("position", 1)
                context?.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    class GreetingsView(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        var imageView: ImageView? = null
        var category: TextView? = null
        var cardView: FrameLayout? = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view)
        var context: Context? = itemView.context
        private var listOfGreetings: List<GreetingModel>? = null

        init {
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.greetingImage)
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.greetingCategory)
            this.listOfGreetings = listOfGreetings
        }
    }
```